# Может ли программа открывшая сетевой порт обратиться к любому другому порту другого PC?

Tags: сеть, сетевое-программирование

Мне непонятно как работает браузер. Причем не конкретный, а сетевая составляющая браузеров в принципе. Допустим https не существует и вообще все сайты работают на 80'м порту. Как браузер может так быстро (может быть даже параллельно) делать уйму запросов к нескольким сайтам, ведь сайты используют всякие там CDN'ы и ссылки на ресурсы других сайтов. К тому-же у браузера может быть уйма вкладок.

Догадываюсь, что браузер открывает отдельные порты для каждого конкретного сервера, а потом закрывает их, когда все ответы получены, так ли это?

Возможно связанный вопрос: какая причина стала следствием того, что на mac 80й порт заблокирован?

Comment: Что вы называете "открывает порт". Существует 2 типа соединения: 1. вызываем bind/listen и получаем открытый для прослушивания порт (так делает web сервер для 80 порта) и ждем входящих соединений. 2. Вызываем функцию connect и указываем только адрес/порт назначения с кем мы хотим соединиться. ОС выдает нам динамический порт для работы, но он нас особо не заботит, и это обычно не называют 'открыть порт'. Вот браузер и вызывает множество connect в параллель к многим сайтам и получает от них данные

Comment: Ив принципе никто не мешает нам даже сделать bind для исходящего порта, сделать много сокетов с одним и тем же портом и отправить через него запросы на несколько _разных_ сайтов. ОС отлично будет понимать от кого ответы и отдаст их в нужный сокет. При этом у программы (браузера) будет всего один открытый порт. Но так обычно не делают, простого connect с динамическим портом более чем достаточно. На одном ip портов все таки 65535, хватает практически всегда

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ. Хотел бы у вас за одно поинтересоваться: вы сказали, что так обычно не делают, про bind для исходящего порта, для этого есть какая-то причина, нет нужды делать bind или так просто повелось исторически?

Comment: У ОС нет функции 'дай свободный номер порта' и программа делающая bind не может быть уверена, что другая программа не использует тот же порт. В итоге bind вернет ошибку, надо будет пытаться взять другой порт. И можно случайно занять порт, который будет жизненно необходим другой программе, без которого та работать в принципе не сможет. И если уж ОС умеет при connect сама находить свободный порт - почему бы не воспользоваться

Comment: Все понятно, спасибо!